# Streaming mpeg audio from an internet radio station?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I wantto create an application  that can be stream the live radio from a url (http://example.com/manifest.f4m).iam using Microsoft.PlayerFramework but not working .any one have any  idea  about this.

Comment: `but not working` don't post so much details. A blank text is enough.

Comment: i mean want to know which kind of servers are support for windows phone

Comment: Your post lacks any concrete specifics, you need to clarify the technologies you're dealing with.  If you're looking for information about what support for Windows Phone you need to outline all of the technologies you'll be interacting with.  Your question is very nebulous.